# Modify subfloat numbering and position

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats, includegraphics, subfig

I've made a figure with 15 subfloats. Here below, first, what I get and, second, what I would like.
I would like to remove subfloats (m) and keep at the location the two other subfloats on the line but changing the numbering.

Does someone have an idea?

[image: What I have]

[image: What I wish]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox[c]{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 1}}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
  \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 2}}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
  \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 3}}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
  \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 4}}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
  \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 5}}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
    \caption{Fields}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please turn your code fragment into a small document we can compile, starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}` please. Only include the packages and commands that are required for your question, further advice is here for [Minimal Working Examples (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/273733)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace an image (the first in the last row) with an empty box with the same width.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox[c]{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 1}}}%
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
        \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 2}}}%
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
        \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 3}}}%
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
        \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 4}}}%
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
        \raisebox{65pt}{\parbox{.05\textwidth}{\rotatebox{90}{Ligne 5}}}%
        \makebox[.3\textwidth]{}\hfill% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%       \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\hfill
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{Example-Image}}\par
        \caption{Fields}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

- It is simple code by inserting `\subfloats in table. Using` tblr`of`tabularray`package with`counter`and`varwidth` libraries.
- For shorter figure code are used keys `\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=c}˙ of` \adjustbox` packages. It define width of images and move their baselines to images vertical center.
- Contents in the first column is rotated by help of `rotating` and `makecell` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % for vertical center images baseline,
                                % use \adjincludegraphics instead of \includegraphics
\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,        % <===
                varwidth}       % <===
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\setlength\rotheadsize{3em}                % from makecell
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=c}  % from adjustbox
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec={@{} Q[c, m, cmd=\rothead] *{3}{X[c,h]}@{}},
            }
Ligne 1
    & \subfloat[\label{fig1:a1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig1:b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig1:c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}}  \\
Ligne 2
    & \subfloat[\label{fig1:a1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig1:b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig1:c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image}}   \\
Ligne 3
    & \subfloat[\label{fig1:a1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig1:b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig1:c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}}   \\
Ligne 4
    & \subfloat[\label{fig1:a1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}}
        & \subfloat[\label{fig1:b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig1:c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}}   \\
Ligne 5
    & 
        & \subfloat[\label{fig1:b1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}}
            & \subfloat[\label{fig1:c1}]{\adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}}
\end{tblr}
\caption{Fields}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that all your images have the same dimensions.

I set a box with one of the images, so to be able to find its height (useful for “Ligne x”) and to use it as a phantom in the last line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newlength{\dummyheight}
\newsavebox{\dummybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]

% replace example-image with the first image name
\sbox{\dummybox}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
\setlength{\dummyheight}{\ht\dummybox}
\newcommand{\ligne}[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{%
    \makebox[\dummyheight]{Ligne #1}%
  }\space\ignorespaces
}

\ligne{1}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\vspace{-1.5pt}

\ligne{2}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\vspace{-1.5pt}

\ligne{3}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\vspace{-1.5pt}

\ligne{4}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\par

\vspace{-1.5pt}

\ligne{5}
\phantom{\usebox{\dummybox}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{Fields}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Since LaTeX warns about the float being too high by about 6pt, I added some small negative vertical space between rows; in your case you may not need it or need some different length.

Declare the float as `p`, as it surely won't fit a page with text.

[image]